# Any websites with exhaustively long lists of dead planet types?

Tags: science-based, planets, geology, chemistry, worldbuilding-resources

Is there any websites on the web where a long site of semi-plausible worlds can be found?  I am looking for all sorts of weird, colorful worlds that *are lifeless and terrestrial*.  For I think it's fun to have planets that are creul mockeries of Earth all over the place, and it seems that's what reality has in store for us anyways.  I know of Orion's Arm, Planetstar Wiki and the planets Star Control 2 has (though the plausibility of star control world types is on the very, very low side).

I recall Baxter made a list of many strange worlds somewhere too, but not sure where that is.

Any websites out there beyond the ones I have mentioned that have long lists of exotic geochemistries for alien planets?  From my understanding all matter of weird, weird worlds could exist around the galaxy and judging by worlds like Io, Venus and Titan something tells me this is the case.

The website must have three things:

- Lists many types of worlds that are trerrestrial which could plausibly exist.
- Describes what stars it may occur around.
- Describes how abundant said world should be.

Comment: Please identify what would make one resource better than others.  2-3 criteria usually suffice to make things discernible.  I would also recommend removing basically everything after the third paragraph as it doesn't actually aid the question being asked.  Mentioning items you have already thought of doesn't help someone identify a better resource for what you are seeking.

Comment: I've done google searches.  I already have looked at wikipedia and multiple websites including a book on world building and a online PDF on xenology.  I'm asking about more obscure sources that I likely have not ran into that someone else may have heard of.

Comment: CLOSE VOTERS:  Note that this is a resource request and on topic for the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Orion's Arm

Orion's Arm is a [universe project](http://www.orionsarm.com/) authored by many. While it is bursting at the seams with hard sci-fi ideas and creations, I find a lot of it pretty esoteric, with its own lingo that can be hard to penetrate.

However, its strength is certainly is massive depth. There are a lot of contributers who each add information about their speciality, so it is remarkably in depth in many areas.

As far as planets go, there are [a lot of options](http://www.orionsarm.com/eg-topic/45b2e52e9eaac). Not everything on the linked page is a planet, but I counted 70 different types. Here is a [better organized page](http://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/491c78b89879b) with all the planet types.

Good luck. Orion's Arm is something of a TV Tropes black hole of productivity. Don't click those links at work!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a canonical listing of either real exoplanets ( none are known to have life, so 'dead' is moot), or a fictional pan-authorship listing that would have what you have described. 
  I suggest as a starting point, you look through the Memory Beta website at:
http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Planet

While the ST universe may not have the planetary characterization of say - Niven's 'N-space', the classification on Memory Beta may give you resources to work from.
Happy hunting !

Answer (score 2):

It's not a straight list, but the Atomic Rockets site has a [very extensive guide](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/worldbuilding.php) to designing worlds.  Pick your sun, calculate habitable zones (for different biologies, even), climate zones, tectonics, -- even how to figure out how big the planet's sun is in the sky!

It also links to several planet-generators on other sites, although I didn't check those out myself.

Comment: Atomic Rockets is great. The planet generators are okay, I've found more extensive knowledge on this site. But calculating everything yourself is a bit the opposite of a premade list.